# Invariant Violation: View config not found for name view : React Native

Tags: react-native

I am beginner to react native. I have custom reusable components. I am trying to build login form as follow :

I used code in LoginForm.js

```
import Button from './common/Button';
import Card  from './common/Card';
import CardItem from './common/CardItem';
class LoginForm extends Component {
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
    title: 'Title from state'
  };
}

  render() {
    return(
        <Card>
          <CardItem>
           <Button>Login</Button>
          </CardItem>
        </Card>
    );
  }
}
```

Card.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const Card = (props) => {
  return(
    <view>
      { props.children }
    </view>
      );
    }

export default Card;
```

CardItem.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const CardItem = (props) => {
  return(
    <view style={styles.cardItem}>
      { props.children }
    </view>
  );
}
export default CardItem;
```

Button.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const Button = (props) =>{
  return(
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress}>
      <Text>
        {props.children}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

And got this error

```
Invariant Violation: View config not found for name view
        in RCTText (at Text.js:145)
        in TouchableText (at Text.js:266)
        in RCTView (at View.js:43)
        in AnimatedComponent (at TouchableOpacity.js:256)
        in TouchableOpacity (at Button.js:6)
        in Button (at LoginForm.js:25)
        in view (at CardItem.js:6)
        in CardItem (at LoginForm.js:24)
        in view (at Card.js:6)
        in Card (at LoginForm.js:23)
```

If I replace the code LoginForm.js in return with `<Text>` as an example `<Text>Login</Text>` it is working.

Kindly help, what I missed ?

Comment: Can you share details of your components (Card, CardItem and Button) ?

Comment: I updated the question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `Card.js` and `CardItem.js` like below. It should be `View`, not `view`.

Card.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const Card = (props) => {
  return(
    <View>
      { props.children }
    </View>
      );
    }

export default Card;
```

CardItem.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const CardItem = (props) => {
  return(
    <View style={styles.cardItem}>
      { props.children }
    </View>
  );
}
export default CardItem;
```

Comment: I didn't believe that ! Thank you